# Copy folders according to the date of creation

Tags: unix

I would like to copy some folders into a unique main folder (parent dir).
The folders I would like to copy are only those created before a certain day.
Is it possible to do this? If yes, How?

Best

Comment: you can use mtime to do this

Comment: Similar : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116174/copy-files-based-on-date-time-from-subset-of-directories

Comment: What programming language? If this isn't a programming question, it should be moved to the [UNIX & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [find](/questions/tagged/find) :

```
$ find -mtime +365 -type d -exec cp {} /another/dir +
```

365 is the number of days (modification date)

Comment: Sorry...but it is unable to copy folders in the main dir. The error is: find: illegal option -- m" and "find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+" . What does it mean?

Comment: Can you test with GNU find ?